Python Tkinter how to set and highlight a listbox selection
I have a listbox which I want to set according to data from elsewhere in my program
options = tk.Variable(('Active', 'Inactive', 'OOC'))
ttk.Label(
    self,
    text='Status',
).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='ne', padx=5)

self.widgets['status'] = tk.Listbox(
    self,
    listvariable=options,
    height=3,
    selectmode=tk.SINGLE,
)

self.widgets['status'].grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='ew', padx=(0, 5), columnspan=4)

if data:
    self.widgets['status'].selection_clear(0, tk.END)
    self.widgets['status'].selection_set(data[4])
    self.widgets['status'].activate(data[4])

The code above works in that it sets the listbox to the correct item - if I tab to the listbox, the item is surrounded by a dotted box - but does not highlight it. After a lot of searching, the only suggested solution I've found is to add self.widgets['status'].event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>') but this doesn't work for me.  How do I get the selected item highlighted?

There is no item selected by default after the listbox is created even it has take the keyboard focus (after you tab to the listbox).  The item surrounded by a dotted box is the active item, not the selected item.

OK, I get that, thank you. So, how do I make it the selected item?

You know already, use selection_set()

I don't think I'm explaining myself very well, sorry. When I click on an item in the listbox, it gets highlighted by the background changing colour, but when I use selection_set() to select an item, the background stays plain white, with no highlighting to indicate which selection has been set. Why? What am I doing wrong and how do I get that background colour change to indicate the selected item?

I don't have such issue.  I can set and highlight the item I want using selection_set().
